# How can I build a node project and a spring-boot project at the same time through a maven

Tags: node.js, spring, angular, maven, spring-boot

I have created a web application with a spring-boot/java backend and an angular/node front end that is encapsulated in a maven wrapper. I would like to launch both parts of the application in sync using the maven wrapper.

When starting the project, I want to execute  `npm install` and `npm start` on the node project and spring-boot:run on the spring boot project. Is there a maven plugin that I can use in my maven wrapper to make this possible?

What is the optimal way of linking these projects and running them simultaneously?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/phillipgreenii/7c954e3c3911e5c32bd0

Answer (score -1):

You will use this maven plugin to call node npm yarn or other like this

```
  <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                        <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${frontend-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>install node and yarn</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>install-node-and-yarn</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <nodeVersion>${node.version}</nodeVersion>
                                    <yarnVersion>${yarn.version}</yarnVersion>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>yarn install</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>yarn</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <arguments>install</arguments>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>webpack build test</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>yarn</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>test</phase>
                                <configuration>
                                    <arguments>run webpack:test</arguments>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>webpack build prod</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>yarn</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                                <configuration>
                                    <arguments>run webpack:prod</arguments>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
```